# Postgres среднее арифметическое

Tags: postgresql

как можно одним запросом получить среднее арифметическое за определенный диапазон?

(C6*D6+F6*G6+I6*J6+L6*M6+O6*P6+R6*S6+U6*V6+X6*Y6)/AG6

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь, что я правильно понял описание вашей проблемы.
Я подготовил тестовый пример ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1fd9b/3))

```
create table testxy (id serial, x integer, y integer);
insert into testxy (x,y) values(2,4),(6,5),(8,6),(10,8),(11,3),(20,2),(15,1),(12,7),(17,2);
```

и сам запрос:

```
select sum(x*y)*1.0/sum(x) as avg_range
from testxy
where id between 2 and 6;
```

Для указанного диапазона, ответ: 4.2

Если, это не то, что вы хотели, то уточните условие задачи.

Comment: where id between 2 and 6; излишне в принципе. число пар я знаю. а так да - то что надо